# How can I make my text be vertically aligned within a DIV?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-tables

I have this code:

```
<div style="font-size: 1.5rem; width: 20%;vertical-align: middle;" >ABC</div>
```

When I look at the page it shows like this. I added x's to show the boundary of the DIV:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x             x
x ABC         x
x             x
x             x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It seems like the vertical-align is not doing anything.

Is there I can make it so that the space above and below the ABC is the same.  I saw CSS tables and Flex.  Is there a way I can do it with standard CSS or do I need to use something like CSS tables or Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one way to solve this without `display: table;` and `display: flex`. It's a bit tricky, but works ok.

To start with, your snipped does not work like this, because the `vertical-align` property applies to inline and table-cell boxes only. A `<div>` is `display: block` by default and therefore out of scope.

So, what can we do? This:

```css
.vertical-align-content
{
  height: 150px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.vertical-align-content > span,
.vertical-align-content::before
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-align-content::before
{
  height: inherit;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-align-content">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

This solution is placing a pseudo element insde of `.vertical-align-content` with the height inherited of the parent container. The pseudo element and the `<span>` are both set to `display: inline-block` and can therefore be positioned using `vertical-align`. The biggest item (the pseudo element) will force the span to be aligned vertically centered to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Used to **[display](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)** property  as like this

```
display:table-cell;
```

-

```html
<div style="font-size: 1.5rem;border:solid 1px red; height:100px; width: 20%;display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle;" >abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<div style="display: table; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">abc</div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/SVJaK/2754/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use line-height?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVJaK/2757/

```
<div class="test">ABC</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test {
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 200px;
   line-height: 200px;
}
```